# Undefined function in node.js REPL session from js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface, read-eval-print-loop

I have a test js script to load into REPL session:

```
// testRepl.js
const cls = () => console.clear();
const msg = txt => console.info(txt);
const ajax = url => msg(url);
```

I am loading this file in REPL using the following command

```
> node
> .load .testRepl.js
```

The problem is that REPL session can load cls and msg functions, but is unable to identify ajax, as displayed in the following image:

[image: ajax is is unidentified]

So this works:

```
> cls()
> msg("Hello")
```

But this fails:

```
> ajax("Hello World!")
```

**EDIT**

This is the code exactly in my testRepl.js:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you don't have a newline at the end of your .js file or something, because trying to reproduce the issue it all works for me:

```
$ cat /tmp/foo.js
const cls = () => console.clear();
const msg = txt => console.info(txt);
const ajax = url => msg(url);

$ node
Welcome to Node.js v16.16.0.
Type ".help" for more information.
> .load /tmp/foo.js
const cls = () => console.clear();
const msg = txt => console.info(txt);
const ajax = url => msg(url);

undefined
> ajax
[Function: ajax]
```

Tried in node v16, v18 and v20.  All the same results.

Comment: "don't have a  newline at the end of your .js file", was the issue. I didn't know we need a newline in end for a REPL session

Comment: It was totally a guess on my end...but I've been burned by similar in the past.  I couldn't seem to reproduce the issue but that could be variation in shells, operating systems, versions of node, etc...